# Construir array asociativo con lineas de txt

Tags: php, array

Hola tengo un txt que tiene la siguiente estructura

```
[HEADER]
7894=12.01
1124=456
2234=1.0
2222=2.3
[DATAOUT]
1235=7
1006=10.0
1007=10
[ENDOFFILE]
```

lo estoy leyendo desde PHP asi:

```
$archivo = fopen('archivo.txt','r');
$data_archivo=array();
while ($linea= fgets($archivo)) {
            $data_archivo[] = $linea;
}
```

ahora a ese array lo recorro asi:

```
$data_final=array();
foreach ($data_archivo as $d) {
 $valor=substr($dato,6,20);
 $codigo=substr($dato,0,5);
if ($codigo=='7894' || $codigo=='1124', etc.){
$data_final=$valor;
}
}
```

me devuelve un array
0=>12, 
1=>0.1,
etc

lo que desearía es armar un array asociativo

{'a'=>12,
'b'=>0.1,
etc.}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias utilizar el codigo como llave de esta manera:

```
$data_final=array();
foreach ($data_archivo as $d) {
  $valor=substr($dato,6,20);
  $codigo=substr($dato,0,5);
  if ($codigo=='7894' || $codigo=='1124', etc.){
    $data_final[$codigo]=$valor;
  }
}
```

Comment: Estimado muchas gracias, justo lo que nesecitaba... de hecho ya quedo, con esos codigos va bien... GRACIAS TOTALES

Comment: Aunque se podría hacer un split mejor. y luego se puede hacer una validación preguntando si los valores que se obtienen son enteros para tener certeza de no ir a tomar valores no validos.